# Ripple effect is not visible on the complete row

Tags: android, rippledrawable

I have a RecyclerView with a row that has a checkmark and a drag & drop (rearrange) icon to the right. Just like in the [official material design video](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-components%2Fassets%2F1dtprsH4jZ2nOnjBCJeJXd7n4U-jmWyas%2F03-list-reorder.mp4), I want the ripple effect to be over the whole row. But when I span the ImageView, the CheckBox is not clickable anymore. Is this even possible?

```
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/small_margin">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:checked="@{safeUnbox(viewModel.isEnabled), default=false}"
            android:padding="@dimen/small_margin"
            android:text="@={viewModel.abbreviation}"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title"
            tools:text="Bijbelvertaling" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dragger"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_drag_handle_24px"
            android:contentDescription="Drag and drop icon" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Apply `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` to parent layout, here probably `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `FrameLayout` use `RelativeLayout` like below and apply ripple effect `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` to root layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/small_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/small_margin">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:checked="@{safeUnbox(viewModel.isEnabled), default=false}"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_margin"
        android:text="@={viewModel.abbreviation}"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Compat.Notification.Title"
        tools:text="Bijbelvertaling" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dragger"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_drag_handle_24px"
        android:contentDescription="Drag and drop icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: With this solution, I get a ripple effect when clicking on the space between the checkbox and the imageView, which looks better than before. But no ripple effect when pressing the ImageView (as shown in the material design video).

Comment: @JimClermonts, This is expected behavior for list as your other items in the list has their own press effect. Check the output